# std::set_union vector<pair<string,string>>

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, set-union

I want to compute the union between two vectors:

`std::vector<pair<string,string>> p1;`

`std::vector<pair<string,string>> p2;`

The problem is that why is the union being done on the second element instead of first?
the size of the union should be equal to **4**. Is it possible to modify set_union so that the Union is done on the first element?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<pair<string,string>> p1;
    std::vector<pair<string,string>> p2;
    p1.push_back(make_pair("A","1"));
    p1.push_back(make_pair("B","2"));
    p1.push_back(make_pair("C","3"));;
    p2.push_back(make_pair("A","4"));
    p2.push_back(make_pair("B","5"));
    p2.push_back(make_pair("C","6"));
    p2.push_back(make_pair("D","7"));
    //sort vectors according to first element
    sort(p1.begin(), p1.end(), [](const pair<string,string>& lhs, const pair<string,string>& rhs) {return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
    sort(p2.begin(), p2.end(), [](const pair<string,string>& lhs, const pair<string,string>& rhs) {return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
    //initialize vectors
    std::vector<pair<string,string>> v(p1.size() + p2.size());
    std::vector<pair<string,string>>::iterator it;
    //compute union
    it=std::set_union(p1.begin(), p1.end(),p2.begin(), p2.end(), v.begin());
    v.resize(it-v.begin());
    //print size
    //size = 4
    cout << v.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The union is done on the `pair`s, with the default `operator<`. `("A", "1")` is different from `("A", "4")`.

Give your comparator to `std::set_union` to achieve the expected result:

```
it=std::set_union(p1.begin(), p1.end(),p2.begin(), p2.end(), v.begin(),
    [](const pair<string,string>& lhs, const pair<string,string>& rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
```

---

Notice 1:

You should also name your lamda instead of typing it several times.

And I would use `v.reserve` and `back_inserter(v)` instead allocating the vector and using  `v.begin()` to collect output:

```
 (...)
    //save comparator
    auto comp = [](const pair<string,string>& lhs, const pair<string,string>& rhs) {return lhs.first < rhs.first; };
    //sort vectors according to first element
    sort(p1.begin(), p1.end(), comp);
    sort(p2.begin(), p2.end(), comp);
    //initialize vectors
    std::vector<pair<string,string>> v;
    v.reserve(p1.size() + p2.size());
    //compute union
    std::set_union(p1.begin(), p1.end(), p2.begin(), p2.end(), back_inserter(v), comp);
    //print size
    //size == 4
    cout << v.size() << endl;
}
```

---

Notice 2: what you do is similar to [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Comment: thank you @Csq. I actually have a comment. What you did for the `std::vector<pair<string,string` can also be done for any structure right?

For every stl I can add a lambda function

Comment: @HaniGoc Yes, you can replace `vector` with any container providing input iterators and `pair<string, string>` with any class.

Comment: @Csq the operator. the operator for set_union is <?

Comment: @HaniGoc If you omit the comparator, [`set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) it sorts using the default `operator<`.